# Using HighchartsExport Library for .Net I am getting Blank Page

Tags: asp.net, highcharts

I am working on embedding HighStock/HighCharts into our site and we want to enable users to export the charts without sending the data off to the HighCharts servers to render the jpg/pdf/svg etc. The only ASP.NET wrapper I could find is [this](https://github.com/imclem/Highcharts-export-module-asp.net). This worked well on a local demo build but integrating this into our product site is giving a blank page for:
http://oursite.com/path/where/called/HighchartsExport.axd

Following the sparse documentation I verified that I had added a reference to the 3 DLLs needed. Our site already uses the `requestValidationMode` needed (2.0). So I added just the httpHandlers item:

```
<add verb="POST" path="HighchartsExport.axd" type="Tek4.Highcharts.Exporting.HttpHandler, Tek4.Highcharts.Exporting"/>
```

I am not sure what else is needed here to get this to work. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: FYI : In Asp .net core comes with Microsoft.Aspnet.Nodeservices, through which we can trigger Highcharts **new** node-export-server and get back chart as a image. You can check the sample implementation [using nodeservices](https://davidsekar.com/angular/server-side-rendering-of-highcharts-in-net-core)

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps it helps to run a [chart.getSVG()](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Chart.getSVG%28%29) before you send the SVG to the ASP.NET export-module. This will sanitize the SVG representing the chart.

When this asp exporting module isn't working for you, you could consider using PhantomJS and run a shell command with the [Highcharts convert script](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/exporting-server/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js) for PhantomJS. Or perhaps run this script as an internal webserver and do an POST request from your .NET application. This is how  the java export-server of Highcharts is working in general. Read more on Highcharts, PhantomJS and exporting to images [here](http://docs.highcharts.com/#render-charts-on-the-server)

Comment: We have actually tried to move to the highcharts-export Java server. I have a question open regarding trying to get it to work under Windows in the latest build - it used to work back in January but it looks like the configuration options are different.

Comment: Yes Highcharts upgraded this server. Before it used both Batik and PhantomJS under the hood, now only PhantomJS. I answered your question by the way, [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670730/highcharts-export-server-2-0-1-errors-under-windows/16737983#16737983).

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue before, the issue was in a part of the HTML rendered that caused error while exporting.
if there is a clip-path tag in your chart HTML, try to remove it before export.

Comment: Not sure what you are referring to. It is a basic line chart (or any basic chart...used as an example). If highcharts is adding a clipPath to the SVG then there is not much I can do - I am not manually adding one.

Comment: the issue is that you are not using HighCharts export, so some some issues may happen while exporting using third party. 
some of the tags generated by HighCharts are not understood by other exporting tools. 
In my case I edited the generated HTML in run time and then exported it, and it worked fine.

Comment: Not really. If I made a stand-alone site and just added a static chart + this export .NET library I get the export working. But, when integrated with our full site it does not export with the same static chart. So, there is some conflict with our internals vs what the .NET library expects.