# Highcharts-Export Server 2.0.1 Errors Under Windows

Tags: java, highcharts, jetty

**EDIT:** Solution was to place all phatomJS related scripts into the Scripts directory and make sure none of the items are read-only for Windows.
My scripts and phantomjs.exe all exist here: `C:\jetty-distribution-9.0.0.M3\webapps\ROOT\Scripts\phantomjs`.

The `app.properties` file has this config:

```
# location of the phantomjs executable, could be for example /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
exec = C:/jetty-distribution-9.0.0.M3/webapps/ROOT/Scripts/phantomjs/phantomjs.exe
# location of convert script used by phantomjs, optional to leave the script property empty, than it's using the script located in: /WEB-INF/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js. This is tested in TOMCAT, but specify a path if resource loading isn't working with the classloader (f.e. with Jetty server), script = a/path/to/my/phantomjs-script.js
script = C:/jetty-distribution-9.0.0.M3/webapps/ROOT/Scripts/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js
```

I can now export via the demo loaded here `http://localhost:8080/highcharts-export/demo` and also call to it via our web site by using `url: 'http://localhost:8080/highcharts-export/'`

*EDIT:*
**Has anyone got a working app.properties file for working under Windows and Jetty?**

I have resolved some of these issues listed below by making this modification to app.properties:

```
# location of the phantomjs executable, could be for example /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
exec = "C:\\jetty-distribution-9.0.0.M3\\webapps\\ROOT\\Scripts\\phantomjs\\phantomjs.exe"

# location of convert script used by phantomjs, optional to leave the script property empty, than it's using the script located in: /WEB-INF/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js. This is tested in TOMCAT, but specify a path if resource loading isn't working with the classloader (f.e. with Jetty server), script = a/path/to/my/phantomjs-script.js
script = /WEB-INF/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js
```

Other variants of the `exec` value with the same results:

```
C:\\jetty-distribution-9.0.0.M3\\webapps\\ROOT\\Scripts\\phantomjs\\phantomjs.exe
C:/jetty-distribution-9.0.0.M3/webapps/ROOT/Scripts/phantomjs/phantomjs.exe
C:\jetty-distribution-9.0.0.M3\webapps\ROOT\Scripts\phantomjs\phantomjs.exe
```

I can now get the demo up at `http://localhost:8080/highcharts-export/demo` butlooking at the output of jetty I am flooded with things like:

```
        [ERROR] [pool-1-thread-1 02:55:19] (TaskUtils.java:handleError:95) Unexpected error occurred in sche
duled task.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error, PhantomJS couldnot start
        at com.highcharts.export.server.Server.<init>(Server.java:56)
        at com.highcharts.export.pool.ServerObjectFactory.create(ServerObjectFactory.java:36)
        at com.highcharts.export.pool.ServerObjectFactory.create(ServerObjectFactory.java:14)
        at com.highcharts.export.pool.AbstractPool.createObject(AbstractPool.java:26)
        at com.highcharts.export.pool.AbstractPool.poolCleaner(AbstractPool.java:66)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnabl
e.java:64)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErro
rHandlingRunnable.java:53)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(Unknown S
ource)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Original question below:**
This is a follow up to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16593269/building-highcharts-export-server-2-1-fails/16665393?noredirect=1#16665393) question. I can now successfully (according to maven at least) build the latest highcharts-export server. I have only modified the app.properties file like this:

```
# location of the phantomjs executable, could be for example /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
exec = C:/jetty-distribution-9.0.0.M3/webapps/ROOT/Scripts/phantomjs
```

Regardless of the configuration to the location of the phatomjs I get the error listed below.

However, when I load it into jetty I get the following error and am unable to work around this.

```
C:\hc-exporter>mvn jetty:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[WARNING]
[WARNING] Some problems were encountered while building the effective model for com.highcharts.expor
t:highcharts-export:war:2.0.1
[WARNING] 'build.plugins.plugin.version' for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-eclipse-plugin is missin
g. @ line 150, column 12
[WARNING]
[WARNING] It is highly recommended to fix these problems because they threaten the stability of your
 build.
[WARNING]
[WARNING] For this reason, future Maven versions might no longer support building such malformed pro
jects.
[WARNING]
[INFO]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building highcharts-export 2.0.1
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO]
[INFO] >>> jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.2.v20120308:run (default-cli) @ highcharts-export >>>
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:resources (default-resources) @ highcharts-export ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:compile (default-compile) @ highcharts-export ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.5:testResources (default-testResources) @ highcharts-export ---
[debug] execute contextualize
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory C:\hc-exporter\src\test\resources
[INFO]
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:2.5.1:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ highcharts-export ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO]
[INFO] <<< jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.2.v20120308:run (default-cli) @ highcharts-export <<<
[INFO]
[INFO] --- jetty-maven-plugin:8.1.2.v20120308:run (default-cli) @ highcharts-export ---
[INFO] Configuring Jetty for project: highcharts-export
[INFO] webAppSourceDirectory C:\hc-exporter\src\main\webapp does not exist. Defaulting to C:\hc-expo
rter\src\main\webapp
[INFO] Reload Mechanic: manual
[INFO] Classes = C:\hc-exporter\target\classes
[INFO] Added extra scan target:C:\hc-exporter\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\pages
[INFO] Added extra scan target:C:\hc-exporter\src\main\webapp\resources
[INFO] Context path = /export
[INFO] Tmp directory = C:\hc-exporter\target\tmp
[INFO] Web defaults = org/eclipse/jetty/webapp/webdefault.xml
[INFO] Web overrides =  none
[INFO] web.xml file = file:/C:/hc-exporter/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/web.xml
[INFO] Webapp directory = C:\hc-exporter\src\main\webapp
2013-05-21 09:00:07.656:INFO:oejs.Server:jetty-8.1.2.v20120308
2013-05-21 09:00:07.987:INFO:oejpw.PlusConfiguration:No Transaction manager found - if your webapp r
equires one, please configure one.
2013-05-21 09:00:09.162:INFO:/export:No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath

2013-05-21 09:00:09.477:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/export,file:/C
:/hc-exporter/src/main/webapp/},file:/C:/hc-exporter/src/main/webapp/
2013-05-21 09:00:09.478:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/export,file:/C
:/hc-exporter/src/main/webapp/},file:/C:/hc-exporter/src/main/webapp/
2013-05-21 09:00:09.482:INFO:oejsh.ContextHandler:started o.m.j.p.JettyWebAppContext{/export,file:/C
:/hc-exporter/src/main/webapp/},file:/C:/hc-exporter/src/main/webapp/
2013-05-21 09:00:09.532:INFO:/export:Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
[ERROR] [main 09:00:10] (ContextLoader.java:initWebApplicationContext:307) Context initialization fa
iled
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'serverObject
Factory': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
        at...
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're getting a Beancreation exception because the @PostConstruct afterBeanInit method is failing.

When you leave the 'script' property in the app.properties file empty, it tries to load the highcharts-convert file with the ClassLoader. [See here](https://github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/blob/master/exporting-server/java/highcharts-export/src/main/java/com/highcharts/export/pool/ServerObjectFactory.java#L152).

As stated in the app.properties file, this is only tested in Tomcat. Clearly this isn't working out of the box for Jetty. Perhaps, because the ClassLoader is different, or maybe you have to deploy the application as an exploded war?

But the easy way, is to specify the 'script' property in the app.properties file. Note that the mandatory files used by the highcharts-convert.js script must also be present in the same folder.

Code Sample of the property file, used by me under windows with Jetty.

```
#### phantomjs properties ####

# the host and port phantomjs listens to
host = 127.0.0.1
port = 7777

# location of the phantomjs executable, could be for example /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
exec = phantomjs

# location of convert script used by phantomjs, optional to leave the script property    empty, than it's using the script located in: /WEB-INF/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js. This is tested in TOMCAT, but specify a path if resource loading isn't working with the classloader (f.e. with Jetty server), script = a/path/to/my/phantomjs-script.js
script = C:/Users/gert/SRC/highcharts.com/exporting-server/java/highcharts-export/target/highcharts-export/WEB-INF/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js
```

After I changed the app.properties file, I build the war with `mvn clean package`

and copied the war file to the Jetty webapps folder. and it worked.

Comment: I am assuming that the phantomjs executable is already in your Windows PATH, correct? My set up looks like this now: `exec = C:/jetty-distribution-9.0.0.M3/webapps/ROOT/Scripts/phantomjs/phantomjs.exe
script = C:/jetty-distribution-9.0.0.M3/webapps/ROOT/Scripts/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js` However I am getting errors like 'ServerObjectFactory.java:validate:55) Error while validating object in Pool: connect timed out.  I left the host/port at default so not sure what is going on here.

Comment: When I try and call an export from a chart to this server I am getting "Timeout converting SVG, is your file this big, or maybe you have a syntax error in the javascript callback?" This chart is not large at all.

Comment: Would this be something better served under HighCharts support. We actually just renewed our support today!

Comment: Try to test the PhantomJs part of the highcharts.js server. Start phantomjs as webserver. Like this: phantomjs.exe highcharts-convert.js  -host 127.0.0.1 -port 7777. And POST with     "{"infile":"{xAxis: {categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']},series: [{data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]}]};","callback":"function(chart) {chart.renderer.arc(200, 150, 100, 50, -Math.PI, 0).attr({fill : '#FCFFC5',stroke : 'black','stroke-width' : 1}).add();}","constr":"Chart","outfile":"chart.png"}"

Comment: Maybe you stumble upon some errors, which can help you to solve this. Any errors you see, when starting up the java application? Are you using the latest phantomjs [highcharts-convert.js](https://raw.github.com/highslide-software/highcharts.com/master/exporting-server/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js) ? We could solve this, I just copied from the repo and did the steps I described in my answer. Just hang in there.

Comment: I successfully ran `phantomjs.exe highcharts-convert.js -host 127.0.0.1 -port 7777` from the command line. I get "OK, PhantomJS is ready." message. How to POST, though?

Comment: I got latest highcharts export server (including the highcharts-convert.js file) 2 days ago - after the patch for adding ACTIVE to server state. I also got latest PhatomJS.

Comment: Use for example the curl command [see here](http://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request) for an example. Or use for example [Postman](http://www.getpostman.com/) they have a plugin for every webbrowser

Comment: Using Postman (very cool!) I set it up as POST HTTP/1.1 Host: 127.0.0.1:7777 Cache-Control: no-cache. My POST request is `"{"infile":"{xAxis: {categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']},series: [{data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]}]};","callback":"function(chart) {chart.renderer.arc(200, 150, 100, 50, -Math.PI, 0).attr({fill : '#FCFFC5',stroke : 'black','stroke-width' : 1}).add();}","constr":"Chart","outfile":"chart.png"}"` and response was "SyntaxError: Unable to parse JSON string".
`

Comment: Doing tests with just command line calls (not server) I can output the chart using the `-infile` with my test chart that I have been trying to use. So it looks like there is something with either how I am sending data down to the server version of phantomJS or how it is configured.

Comment: Removing the outer quotes allowed me to return data via Postman. The POST request is `{"infile":"{series: [{data: [1,2,3,4,5]}]};","constr":"Chart","outfile":"OUT.svg"}`. Still unable to get it to work when compiled into a WAR.

Comment: It was a Windows read-only issue with the highcharts exporting JS files!

Answer (score 0):

Your first example above indicates you are configuring to point at jetty 9.0.0.M3 (9.0.3.v20130506 is latest) but your second example shows you using the jetty-maven-plugin 8.1.2 (8.1.10.v20130312 is the latest) which does not make use of any jetty distribution, it uses an embedded instance of jetty that it wires up and starts via the maven plugin.

You need to decide how you are going to run jetty, either via a distribution (your first example) or via the maven plugin (org.eclipse.jetty:jetty-maven-plugin:9.0.3.v20130506 is probably one you should use) and configure your 'exec =' property accordingly.

Comment: Jesse, yes. Sorry for the mixed examples there. The development test is using jetty 9M3. And I get the same error when I load it there. The error message here is spit out when I do a `mvn jetty:run`. Either way I get this error on `serverObjectFactory`.

Comment: ah, in that case its not jetty specifically related (unless it is classpath configuration related), sort out what the NPE is here: com.highcharts.export.pool.ServerObjectFactory.afterBeanInit(ServerObjectFactory.java:157

Comment: OT but why didn't maven catch this during build?

Comment: because it was a runtime error and any test cases did not cover this case