# highcharts setup export server on windows error

Tags: highcharts

I have some problem with highcharts when I setup export server.
My directory structure as following:

```
C:\HighChart --|
     highcharts-export --|
        highcharts-export-convert
        highcharts-export-web
        pom.xml
     phantomjs --|
        phantomjs.exe
```

And I edit the app-convert.properties(which in C:\HighChart\highcharts-export\highcharts-export-web\src\main\webapp\WEB-INF\spring) as following:

```
#### phantomjs properties ####

# the host and port phantomjs listens to
host = 127.0.0.1
port = 7777

# location of the phantomjs executable, could be for example /usr/local/bin/phantomjs
exec = C:/HighChart/phantomjs/phantomjs.exe

# name of the convert script used by phantomjs
script = C:/HighChart/highcharts-export/highcharts-export-convert/src/main/resources/phantomjs/highcharts-convert.js

#### connect properties used to connect with phantomjs running as HTTP-server ####
# all values in milliseconds

# specifies the timeout when reading from phantomjs when a connection is established
readTimeout = 6000

# timeout to be used when opening a communications link to the phantomjs server
connectTimeout = 500

# the whole request to the phantomjs server is scheduled, max timeout can last to this      value. This is because in java you can't rely on the above two timeouts.
maxTimeout = 6500

#### Pool properties ####

# number of phantomjs servers you can run in the pool.
poolSize = 5

# The pool is implemented as a BlockingQueue. When asking for a phantom server connection and nothing is available, it waits for the number of milliseconds defined by maxWait
maxWait = 500

# Keep files in the temp folder for a certain retentionTime, defined in miliseconds
retentionTime = 30000
```

And finally I type `mvn clean package` create a .war file, and fire it both jetty and tomcat,but when the server startup, it occur an error as following:

```
[ERROR] [pool-1-thread-1] (TaskUtils.java:handleError:95) Unexpected error occurred in scheduled task.
java.lang.RuntimeException: Error,PhantomJS couldnot start
      at com.highcharts.export.server.Server.<init>(Server.java:60)....
```

And I also change the exec and script in app-convert.properties serval times but when i start server it's always like this...
Need help!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highcharts-Export Server 2.0.1 Errors Under Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670730/highcharts-export-server-2-0-1-errors-under-windows)

Comment: The solution I found was to make sure that the owner of the directory for phantomJS is the one running jetty/tomcat. I also had to force that entire phantomJS location to not be Read Only.

Comment: @wergeld I try to do this but also failed.