# phantomjs and highcharts: too many phantomjs.exe process in Windows/Eclipse/Java development

Tags: eclipse, windows, highcharts, jetty, phantomjs

I am doing development now with highcharts on Windows/Eclipse/Jetty/Java environment.

I have the following highcharts-convert.properties:

```
#### phantomjs properties ####
# the host and port phantomjs listens to
host = 127.0.0.1
port = 7777
# location of the phantomjs executable 
exec = phantomjs
# name of the convert script used by phantomjs
script = highcharts-convert.js
#### connect properties used to connect with phantomjs running as HTTP-server ####
# all values in milliseconds
# specifies the timeout when reading from phantomjs when a connection is established
readTimeout = 6000
# timeout to be used when opening a communications link to the phantomjs server
connectTimeout = 500
# the whole request to the phantomjs server is scheduled, max timeout can last to this value.  
maxTimeout = 6500
#### Pool properties ####
# number of phantomjs servers you can run in the pool.
poolSize = 6
# The pool is implemented as a BlockingQueue.  
maxWait = 500
# Keep files in the temp folder for a certain retentionTime, defined in miliseconds
retentionTime = 30000
```

I have to constantly start, stop, and restart Jetty within Eclipse. I notice that each time I start jetty, 6 window processes called p"hantomjs.exe *32" are started. However, when I stop Jetty, these process do not disappear. This leads to too many "phantomjs.exe *32" running on my machine.

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I'm not sure about eclipse, but have you seen [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670730/highcharts-export-server-2-0-1-errors-under-windows) ? Also [this one](http://forum.highcharts.com/highcharts-usage/export-server-setup-error-converting-svgconnection-refused-t30561/).

Comment: Pawel, nice to hear you again. I just read the two links you mentioned. They are not related to my situation. I have got everything working properly  except this issue. Thanks, again!!

Comment: I thought so, anyway, looks like some problem with exporting server -> I suggest to contact with Highcharts support on email.